# Assure correct alignment on std::string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, alignment, stdstring

Compiling this header:

```
// myheader.h

class MyClass {

    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    unsigned int mMyUint;
    bool bMyBool;
    std::string sMyString;
};
```

with Visual Studio 2010 /W4 (I was told to do so), target x64, gives me the following `warning C4121`:

`'MyClass' : alignment of a member was sensitive to packing`, referring to line where the `std::string sMyString` is. The [official help of Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabt0ka3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) proposes to use a `#pragma pack(x)`, where `x` be 1, 2, 4 dependent on the members one uses inside its struct / class.

No I wonder which alignment to use for std::string? My idea was that std::string is nor compiler neither platform independent. Is there any way to resolve that issue especially considering the other members which may have any other aligment?

Best would be a compiler-independent (and even portable) solution.

**Update:** Concerning the very useful answer provided by jalf: No, in this file I am not using a `#pragma pack(x)`. I used it in another struct where I use Bit-fields which I have seen are padded when not using the `#pragma pack(x)`. Now I was just alarmed to run into the same trap because I did not know how the Microsoft compiler resolves `std::string`.

Comment: It just tells you that there is space within your structure. You should not pack it for no reason. Rearranging the members might make this silly warning go away, just ignore it.

Comment: Re. your update: try copying this class definition to a separate file and compiling that in isolation, without including anything unnecessary. If that still produces the warning, then it is just Microsoft being silly. Otherwise, it is something from the rest of your code (such as a `#pragma pack(push)`, with no corresponding `pop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler-independent and portable solution is **exactly** the code that you have shown us. The compiler takes care of aligning everything correctly if you don't do anything to disrupt it. (such as using SIMD types which require special alignment, or using `#pragma pack`)

If you're using a `#pragma pack`, then:

1. why didn't you show us?
2. *don't*.

If the code you have shown us gives you any warnings at /W4, blame Microsoft. The code is correct, portable and safe (*unlike* code which uses the `pack` pragma).

Microsoft has some weird ideas about warnings at /W4. Most compilers only issue warnings for things that look like they *might* contain errors.

Microsoft has a whole load of warnings basically saying "I have no reason to suspect that there is a problem with this code, but if you had written it differently, it might contain a bug", which is pure nonsense.

With other compilers I generally recommend compiling with all warnings enabled. On Microsoft's compiler, that's not really viable. (Although you can use /W4, and selectively silence specific nonsense warnings)

What I *think* they're specifically telling you is that the structure contains padding bytes (and so, if you *did* use `#pragma pack`, it would alter the layout of the class, and one of the affected class members would be "sensitive" to this change).

If possible, consider rearranging the class members so they are listed in descending order of size. That gives you more compact class layouts, with padding (if any) only at the end of the class.

But there is nothing *wrong* with the class definition you're currently using.

Comment: there is Something that op  isn't telling  us. msvc doesnt  just generate this warning for no reason.

Comment: @JohnDibling yeah, I suspect as much (see my comment on the question). But given just the code we've been shown, there is nothing wrong with the code. (And I didn't have a Windows machine at hand to test it on to see if I could provoke the warning). But yeah, I agree. It sems as if he's doing something else somewhere, which is causing the class to be packed